# Java: Arrays Exception in thread

Tags: java

Why the code doesn't print out the variable count that I changed threw creating array object?

```
public class EchoTestDrive {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Echo[] pets;
    pets = new Echo[7];
    pets[0] = new Echo();
    pets[0].count = 43;
    pets[1].count = 50;
    **System.out.println(pets[0].count);**//doesn't prints out
    **System.out.println(pets[1].count);**//doesn't prints out
    //prints out: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    // at EchoTestDrive.main(EchoTestDrive.java:8)
}
}
```

**Another class**:

```
public class Echo {
int count = 0;
void hello(){
    System.out.println("helloooo... ");
   }
}
```

Comment: `pets[1]` is `null`, you've not assigned anything to that array element

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pets[1].count = 50;
```

This will raise `java.lang.NullPointerException` as `pets[1]` reference is `null`.

```
System.out.println(pets[0].count);
```

If you commented out the previous line, then this will definitely print 43.

```
System.out.println(pets[1].count);
```

If commented out `pets[1].count = 50;` line, then it would raise same `java.lang.NullPointerException` as `pets[1]` reference is `null`.

In short you forgot to initialise `pets[1]` which should be -

```
pets[1] = new Echo();
```